# Show interception values, matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm ploting some curves `Imax` vs `Ciclo de servicio` for several frequencies.

To do that I'm making two nested sweeps for the independent variables, `Fs` and `Vo`

Although  equations are a bit more complex I'm basically doing this:

```
for Fs in np.linspace(70e3,200e3,4):
    Vo_sweep = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
     delta_I = [I_max(Vo) for Vo in Vo_sweep]
     plt.plot(Vo_sweep,delta_I)
```

[image]

And I'm particularly interested in the point where 'ciclo de servicio' is 0.71.

How Can I show the value 0.71 in the X axes and Y value of the interception of the blue line with each curve

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but if your x-axis has all integer values from 0 to 1000 (that you plot as 0 to 1.0 somehow), isn't the y-value of `x=0.71`just `I_max(709)`? Then you could use an annotate (for example) to write that value into the graph. See here: http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html

Comment: I agree with @StefanS. By construction you already know the value of each function at x=0.71, or the closest x to that. So, my suggestion would be to save I_max(0.71) in a list, and then add a small panel down below that shows I_max(0.71) as a function of frequency. If you have many different curves this would give you a quiet smooth function that can be easily understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to plot your interception markers using arbitrary data (whatever your functions and vertical lines might be) I would advise that you calculate the intersection points (where they exist). A few months ago I gave an answer that might be useful to you. You can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479546/python-find-where-the-plot-crosses-the-axhline-on-python-plot/36485568#36485568).

Adapting a similar solution to your problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def line_intersection(line1, line2):
    xdiff = (line1[0][0] - line1[1][0], line2[0][0] - line2[1][0])
    ydiff = (line1[0][1] - line1[1][1], line2[0][1] - line2[1][1]) #Typo was here

    def det(a, b):
        return a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0]

    div = det(xdiff, ydiff)
    if div == 0:
        return None

    d = (det(*line1), det(*line2))
    x = det(d, xdiff) / div
    y = det(d, ydiff) / div
    return x, y

def near(a, b, rtol=1e-5, atol=1e-8):
    return abs(a - b) < (atol + rtol * abs(b))
def crosses(line1, line2):
    """
    Return True if line segment line1 intersects line segment line2 and 
    line1 and line2 are not parallel.
    """
    (x1,y1), (x2,y2) = line1
    (u1,v1), (u2,v2) = line2
    (a,b), (c,d) = (x2-x1, u1-u2), (y2-y1, v1-v2)
    e, f = u1-x1, v1-y1
    denom = float(a*d - b*c)
    if near(denom, 0):
        # parallel
        return False
    else:
        t = (e*d - b*f)/denom
        s = (a*f - e*c)/denom
        # When 0<=t<=1 and 0<=s<=1 the point of intersection occurs within the
        # line segments
        return 0<=t<=1 and 0<=s<=1


for Fs in np.linspace(70e3,200e3,4):
    Vo_sweep = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
    delta_I = [i*Fs*np.log((i+1.1)/10) for i in range(len(Vo_sweep))] #[I_max(Vo) for Vo in Vo_sweep]
    plt.plot(Vo_sweep,delta_I)

plt.vlines(0.71,min(delta_I),max(delta_I))

for Fs in np.linspace(70e3,200e3,4):
    x = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
    y = [i*Fs*np.log((i+1.1)/10) for i in range(len(Vo_sweep))]
    for i in range(1,len(delta_I)):
        p1 = np.array([x[i-1],y[i-1]],dtype='float')
        p2 = np.array([x[i],y[i]],dtype='float')
        k1 = np.array([0.71,min(delta_I)],dtype='float')
        k2 = np.array([0.71,max(delta_I)],dtype='float')
        if crosses((p2,p1),(k1,k2)):
            seg = line_intersection((p2,p1),(k1,k2))
            plt.scatter(seg[0],seg[1],c='red',s=90)
            print(seg)

plt.ylim(min(delta_I),max(delta_I))
plt.xlim(0,1)

plt.show()
```

, which results in this:

[image: Plots markers intercepts matplotlib]

This particular recipe is also printing the interception coordinate if that might be of interest to you:

```
(0.70999999999999985, 211670610.06954533)
(0.70999999999999985, 342704797.25546497)
(0.70999999999999985, 473738984.44138455)
(0.70999999999999985, 604773171.62730408)
```

Since you didn't provided the data I had to make a fast synthetic one but It should be as easy as replacing by your `I_max()` function in the definition of `delta_I`.